# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null

Tags: javascript, android

We've been seeing this error in our web app the last couple of months:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
```

First I noticed it was only happening on android phones with 4.0.X, no other OS or version.

To debug this I started by removing code and markup to try and find the culprit.
I did this until I had completely emptied the document of everything and the problem is still there.

The only clue is the console line before:

```
Reader :: Recognize :: INFO - Script is evaluating. recognizeArticle Start
```

Does anyone have any clue of why this is happening?
The problem is we get notified on errors and we can't ignore this since it's happening on a random line and page every time.

---

I can add that this happens on all our web apps.

---

To clarify, this is not a problem with our web app, the problem is with android.
I've removed ALL our code and markup and the problem is still there, android is doing something that causes this error.

The phone I've tested on was a galaxy S3.

---

Since people don't seem to believe me when I say the source is empty:

```
(develop✗) $ curl -v localhost:3000/us/app
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /us/app HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: c7d96d6898017b5efa7659028008a8b8
< X-Runtime: 0.011019
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: thin 1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Where in (your?) code do you attempt to access property 'tagName' of some objects? At the time of this attempt the object itself is null - i.e. the previous attempt to get object actually failed, but was left unchecked.  
You should be looking for the code like `... someObj.tagName ...` or `... someObj["tagName"] ...`

Comment: I know what the errors means... As I said the error still occurs when I've emptied the DOM of everything (and I mean everything).

Comment: No one would really be able to help you debug your code unless you show the code in question.

Comment: Did you even read the question, there IS no code, I've removed it all. The problem isn't our code.

Comment: I get the same error on an ASP.Net page (Samsung Galaxy S3), but with a line number (Always the same number!): "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null in line 279". The error occurs after all of my own scripts.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I think it's just something we'll have to live with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that on Android 4.0.X any page without a div containing at least 10 characters will throw a JavaScript error.  The RSS reader apparently assumes that the page will have some content in a div.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error on Chrome for Linux and it was caused by the ImageBlocker extension. Since this "error" occurs for you when you launch a blank page, it reasons that you don't need to fix it. It is a bug with the browser or an extension.

Answer (score -3):

Your question combined with your comments do **NOT** make sense:
it sounds like you are opening **empty** page containing **no HTML or JavaScript** and it generates you an error???

There **is** some JavaScript function somewhere in your page that runs and
1) attempts to get some object from your DOM
2) fails to do 1) but does **NOT** handle the error leaving object reference variable set to NULL
3) attempts to use the above object variable to get it's `tagName` property.

If the above were not true than you would **NOT** have an error to ask about.

Comment: Why do you think I'm asking this question?... What I'm saying is I'M not sending any code but something in android is injecting broken code into the browser.

Comment: Does that happen with **EVERY** page/site your are attempting to get to? If not, than it is not likely to be the device/OS.  You **do** know that there maybe extra parts like header and footer that can be added to every page of your site without you actually adding it?
Can you get to the page source code and confirm that there is **NOTHING** there?

Comment: See the `curl` output in the question.

Comment: I understood that you get the error (and therefore the additional script/code) **ONLY** when you access the site from "galaxy S3", did you try to "impersonate" it's browser in cURL?

Comment: So we've written this app from scratch, we have no conditionals for different devices in the rendering.

Comment: If that is the case I suggest you contact Samsung/Google with details of the error as they should be interested to know. Do you know if that happens with **ALL** android phones with 4.0.X or just some?

Comment: I can't see that in our tool sadly :( I think contacting them might be the best idea, though i think they'll play the blame game.